# PL/pgSQL control structures for lists / arrays

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, arraylist, plpgsql, control-structure

Is it possible to use something like this in Postgres? This is the example from PL/SQL what I want to do:

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_PAYMENT(P_AMOUNT IN NUMBER,
                         P_INVOICE_LIST IN SIMPLEARRAYTYPE, 
                         P_AMOUNT_LIST IN NUMBER_TABLE -- pass list of amounts
                            .
                            .
                            .)

s_chk_amnt              NUMBER;

invoice_list SIMPLEARRAYTYPE;
amount_list NUMBER_TABLE;

BEGIN
      -- check if amount list is null or contains zeros
    IF p_amount_list IS NOT NULL AND p_amount_list.COUNT <> 0 THEN
      FOR r IN p_amount_list.FIRST..p_amount_list.LAST
      LOOP
        s_chk_amnt := s_chk_amnt + p_amount_list(r);
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
```

Can I declare a list of characters and list of numbers as function input parameters?
I have found some examples with `FOREACH element` but I don't know how to grab a certain element from number list like in Oracle with `p_amount_list(r)`.

Comment: Explaining more about what this does, without reference to Oracle specifics, might get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CREATE_PAYMENT(p_amount_list numeric[])
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
DECLARE
   s_chk_amnt numeric := 0; -- init variable!
   r          numeric;
BEGIN
-- IF p_amount_list <> '{}' THEN  -- just noise
   FOREACH r IN ARRAY p_amount_list
   LOOP
      s_chk_amnt := s_chk_amnt + r;
   END LOOP;
-- END IF;

RETURN s_chk_amnt;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

#### Major points

- Oracle's `number` is [`numeric` in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html). But if you don't have fractional digits, you'd rather use `int` or `bigint` in Postgres. [About type mapping between Oracle and Postgres.](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.dbi-link/64)
- Postgres does not have ["table types" like Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#CHDGFFAD). Use [array types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html), an array of `numeric` in this case: `numeric[]`.
- The expression `IF p_amount_list <> '{}' ...` would rule out NULL and "empty array" alike. No need for a second check like in your original. But the `IF` is not needed at all. For NULL or empty array, the loop isn't entered anyway.
- `r` holds the element itself, not an index to it. (Therefore it must be a matching data type.)

This goes to demonstrate basic syntax of a `FOREACH` loop in a plpgsql function. Otherwise it would be *expensive nonsense*, better replaced with a much simpler and faster:

```sql
SELECT sum(elem) AS sum_amount
FROM   unnest(p_amount_list) elem;
```

Comment: And what about if I want to pass list of characters? Can I use anyarray or?

Comment: Should the procedure like like this in that case?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CREATE_PAYMENT3(p_inv_list anyarray)
  RETURNS anyarray AS
$func$
DECLARE
   s_inv text; -- init variable!
   r          text;
BEGIN

   FOREACH r IN ARRAY p_inv_list
   LOOP
      s_inv := s_inv || r;
   END LOOP;

RETURN s_inv;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

Comment: @Maki: You might be trying to reinvent [`array_to_string()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). Else, start a new question. Comments are not the place for that. You can always link to this one for context.