# Passing an array to stored to postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Like advised I am linking to my previous question:
[PL/pgSQL control structures for lists / arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708234/pl-pgsql-control-structures-for-lists-arrays)

I want to pass a list of numbers and a list of characters into a Postgres stored procedure. After that I want to do something with those two arrays. For number list you already helped me. I used `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_proc(p_amount_list numeric[])` as input parameter, and when I called that procedure I used `SELECT my_proc('{2,2,2}');`.

Now I want to know how to pass a list of characters and also how to call the procedure after that.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* build a function that either concatenates strings or sums up numeric values depending on the polymorphic input type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION poly_sum_agg(_arr anyarray)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
BEGIN

CASE (SELECT e.typcategory FROM pg_type e
      WHERE  e.oid = (SELECT typelem FROM pg_type WHERE oid = pg_typeof(_arr)))

WHEN 'S' THEN  -- string types: char, name, text, bpchar, varchar
   RETURN array_to_string(_arr, '');  -- no separator?

WHEN 'N' THEN  -- numeric: int8, int2, int4, oid, float4, float8, money, numeric
   RETURN (SELECT sum(elem)::text FROM unnest(_arr) elem);

ELSE
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected array type!';

END CASE;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call (note the explicit **type cast**):

```
SELECT poly_sum_agg('{1,2,3}'::int[]) AS int_arr; -- Returns '6'
```

Or:

```
SELECT poly_sum_agg('{1,2,3}'::text[]) AS text_arr; -- Returns '123'
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/65690/1)

This is just a proof of concept. It builds on the internal representation of array types in the system catalog [`pg_type`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html) and may not be portable across major releases. Here is how I retrieved information fro the system catalog:

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4277)

It's largely unclear what your exact objective is. Depending on what you actually need, I would most probably take a different approach.