# Unnest multiple arrays in parallel

Tags: arrays, postgresql, arraylist, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

My last question [Passing an array to stored to postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823248/passing-an-array-to-stored-to-postgres/27825270#27825270) was a bit unclear. Now, to clarify my objective:

I want to create an Postgres stored procedure which will accept two input parameters. One will be a list of some *amounts* like for instance `(100, 40.5, 76)` and the other one will be list of some *invoices* `('01-2222-05','01-3333-04','01-4444-08')`. After that I want to use these two lists of numbers and characters and do something with them. For example I want to take each amount from this array of numbers and assign it to corresponding invoice.

Something like that in Oracle would look like this:

```
SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_PROCEDURE (
    789,
    SYSDATE,
    SIMPLEARRAYTYPE ('01-2222-05','01-3333-04','01-4444-08'), 
    NUMBER_TABLE (100,40.5,76),
    'EUR',      
    1, 
    P_CODE,
    P_MESSAGE);
```

Of course, the two types `SIMPLEARRAYTYPE` and `NUMBER_TABLE` are defined earlier in DB.

Comment: What is unclear exactly? How to *call* these kind of functions? You can use the array constructors http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS or, you can write their input representation in string (then use casting optionally) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO

Comment: I don't know how to create stored proc with these kinds of input params.

Comment: That is also covered in your previous question(s) (f.ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708234/pl-pgsql-control-structures-for-lists-arrays ) -- you can use the standard compatible `<type> ARRAY`, or the PostgreSQL specific `<type>[]` syntax. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You will *love* this new feature of Postgres **9.4**:

```
unnest(anyarray, anyarray [, ...])
```

`unnest()` with the much anticipated (at least by me) capability to unnest multiple arrays in parallel *cleanly*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> expand multiple arrays (possibly of different types) to a set of rows. This is only allowed in the FROM clause;

It's a special implementation of the new [`ROWS FROM` feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS).

Your function can now just be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_unnest(_some_id int
                                      , _amounts numeric[]
                                      , _invoices text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (some_id int, amount numeric, invoice text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT _some_id, u.* FROM unnest(_amounts, _invoices) u;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM multi_unnest(123, '{100, 40.5, 76}'::numeric[] 
                        , '{01-2222-05,01-3333-04,01-4444-08}'::text[]);
```

Of course, the simple form can be replaced with **plain SQL** (no additional function):

```
SELECT 123 AS some_id, *
FROM unnest('{100, 40.5, 76}'::numeric[]
          , '{01-2222-05,01-3333-04,01-4444-08}'::text[]) AS u(amount, invoice);
```

In earlier versions (Postgres **9.3-**), you can use the less elegant and less safe form:

```
SELECT 123 AS some_id
     , unnest('{100, 40.5, 76}'::numeric[]) AS amount
     , unnest('{01-2222-05,01-3333-04,01-4444-08}'::text[]) AS invoice;
```

Caveats of the old shorthand form: besides being non-standard to have set-returning function in the `SELECT` list, the number of rows returned would be the lowest common multiple of each arrays number of elements (with surprising results for unequal numbers). Details in these related answers:

- [Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830991/parallel-unnest-and-sort-order-in-postgresql/23838131#23838131)
- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)

---

This behavior has finally been sanitized with **Postgres 10**. Multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list produce rows in "lock-step" now. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Comment: The documentation for the "rows from" syntax in the documentation is a little confusing and there is no example. Just for reference `select * from rows from(unnest('{1,2,3}'::integer[]), unnest('{4,5,6}'::integer[]), unnest('{7,8}'::integer[])) u(a, b, c);` will demonstrate basic usage - the "rows from" construction returns a table that can be used in the from clause.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are declared by adding `[]` to the base datatype. You declare them as a parameter the same way you declare regular parameters:

The following function accepts an array of integers and and array of strings and will return some dummy text:

```
create function array_demo(p_data integer[], p_invoices text[])
  returns text
as
$$
  select p_data[1] || ' => ' || p_invoices[1];
$$
language sql;

select array_demo(array[1,2,3], array['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fdb8d/1

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it is okay. Can U use FOREACH over text array?

Comment: Can I use FOREACH over text array in Postgres?

Comment: @Maki: if everything else fails, read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY