# How to unnest an ARRAY of dates in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, date, integer, unnest

I want to do an insert on the following table but I am not able to convert an ARRAY of dates.

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  idschedule serial NOT NULL,
  idzone integer NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  automatic boolean NOT NULL,
  idrecurrence character varying(20),
  duration integer,
  date date,
)
```

The `INSERT` I am trying to perform:

```
INSERT INTO schedule(idzone, "date", "time", duration, automatic) 
SELECT x, y, '20:00:00', '20', 'FALSE' 
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[3,4,5]) x
     , unnest(ARRAY[2015-4-12, 2015-4-19, 2015-4-26]) y
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Column 'date' is of type date But the expression is of type integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An **[array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)** is even simpler than an [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
'{2015-4-12, 2015-4-19}'::date[]
```

With Postgres 9.4 or later, there is a safe way to unnest two arrays in parallel:

```
INSERT INTO schedule
      (idzone, "date", "time"    , duration, automatic) 
SELECT x     , y     , '20:00:00', 20      , false
FROM   unnest('{3, 4, 5}'::int[]
            , '{2015-4-12, 2015-4-19, 2015-4-26}'::date[]
             ) AS t (x, y)  -- produces 3 rows
```

See:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/passing-arrays-to-stored-procedures-in-postgres/27854382#27854382)

Unless you `wanted` to cross join each element of one array to each element of the other to produce a Cartesian product of 9 rows. Then your original form is right.

Aside: It's good practice to *never* use reserved words or basic type names like "date" and "time" as identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

As the error message tells, `2015-4-12` is not a date. It's the number `2015` minus the number `4` minus the number `12`.

You may write an individual date as :

```
'2014-04-12'::date
```

or

```
 date '2015-4-12'
```

A shorter form for an array (avoiding individual casts) would be:

```
ARRAY['2015-4-12', '2015-4-19']::date[]
```

Comment: I just tested and the solution ARRAY['2015-4-12', '2015-4-19']::date[] worked perfect! Thnaks!