# Return column name and distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, set-returning-functions

Say I have a simple table in postgres as the following:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
|  Car   |  Pet   |   Name   |
+--------+--------+----------+
| BMW    |  Dog   |   Sam    |
| Honda  |  Cat   |   Mary   |
| Toyota |  Dog   |   Sam    |
| ...    |  ...   |   ...    |
```

I would like to run a sql query that could return the column name in the first column and unique values in the second column. For example:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Col   |  Vals  |
+--------+--------+
| Car    |  BMW   |
| Car    | Toyota |
| Car    | Honda  |
| Pet    |  Dog   |
| Pet    |  Cat   |
| Name   |  Sam   |
| Name   |  Mary  |
| ...    |  ...   |
```

[I found a bit of code that can be used to return all of the unique values from multiple fields into one column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/select-distinct-on-multiple-columns):

```
-- Query 4b.  (104 ms, 128 ms)
select distinct unnest( array_agg(a)||
                        array_agg(b)||
                        array_agg(c)||
                        array_agg(d) )
from t ;
```

But I don't understand the code well enough to know how to append the column name into another column.

[I also found a query that can return the column names in a table.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table) Maybe a sub-query of this in combination with the "Query 4b" shown above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ced66/6)

```
SELECT distinct
       unnest(array['car', 'pet', 'name']) AS col,
       unnest(array[car, pet, name]) AS vals
FROM t
order by col
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's bad style to put set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list and not allowed in the SQL standard. Postgres supports it for historical reasons, but since `LATERAL` was introduced Postgres 9.3, it's largely obsolete. We can use it here as well:

```
SELECT x.col, x.val
FROM   tbl, LATERAL (VALUES ('car', car)
                          , ('pet', pet)
                          , ('name', name)) x(col, val)
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

You'll find this `LATERAL (VALUES ...)` technique discussed under [the very same question on dba.SE you already found yourself](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/select-distinct-on-multiple-columns). Just don't stop reading at the first answer.

Up until Postgres **9.4** there was still an exception: "parallel unnest" required to combine multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list.  Postgres 9.4 brought a [new variant of `unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to remove that necessity, too. More:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/passing-arrays-to-stored-procedures-in-postgres/27854382#27854382)

The new function is also does not derail into a Cartesian product if the number of returned rows should not be exactly the same for all set-returning functions in the SELECT list, which is (was) a very odd behavior. The new syntax variant should be preferred over the now outdated one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
FROM   tbl t, unnest('{car, pet, name}'::text[]
                   , ARRAY[t.car, t.pet, t.name]) AS x(col, val)
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

Also shorter and faster than two `unnest()` calls in parallel.

Returns:

```
 col  |  val
------+--------
 car  | BMW
 car  | Honda
 car  | Toyota
 name | Mary
 name | Sam
 pet  | Cat
 pet  | Dog
```

`DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`, either is good for the task.

Answer (score 1):

With [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) 
`row_to_json()` and `json_each_text()` you can do it not specifying number and names of columns:

```
select distinct key as col, value as vals
from (
    select row_to_json(t) r
    from a_table t
    ) t,
    json_each_text(r)
order by 1, 2;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ced66/11).