# Single update query from two ordered arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update, unnest

So, lets say I have two ordered arrays with the same number of elements where each index of each array refers to the other one at the same index

```
values = [ 5, 7, 8, 9 ]
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

instead of doing multiple UPDATES inside a loop

```
for thing, index in values
    UPDATE table SET column1 = thing WHERE column2 = keys[index]
```

is there a way to pull these arrays into Postgres and use them in a single `UPDATE` query?

Something like:

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = values[?] WHERE column2 = keys[?]
```

Comment: there isnt a direct way. You need convert those two array into a table with unnest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number

Comment: If you store the keys and values together in an hstore or json object it would be fairly easy to do but nothing direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** there is a way.

Assuming current Postgres 9.5 since you did not specify. Use the new form of `unnest()` to unnest multiple arrays in parallel:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

And use the derived table in a plain `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    column1 = a.value
FROM   unnest ('{5, 7, 8, 9}'::int[]
              ,'{a, b, c, d}'::text[]) AS a(value, key)
WHERE  t.column2 = a.key;
```