# Product of elements with same index in 2 arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I need to multiply each element of 2 arrays and project a column which is a array and each element is the product result.

Example:

```
select * from vetor_query;
```

Returns:

```
query_id |pesos                                                                                               |
---------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1        |{2.0000,0.4150,2.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000} |
```

And the query:

```
select * from vetor_documento;
```

Returns:

```
doc    |pesos                                                                                               |
-------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
d1.txt |{3.0000,0.8301,4.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000} |
d2.txt |{2.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,2.0000,2.0000,2.0000,2.0000,2.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000} |
d3.txt |{0.0000,1.0729,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,2.0000,1.0000,0.0000,2.0000,2.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000} |
d4.txt |{0.0000,1.0729,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,5.1699,4.0000,4.0000} |
```

I need to combine both queries(cross join) and produce as a result array of internal product for each `doc` and `query_id`.

My first attempt was this one:

```
select vq.query_id, vd.doc, unnest(vq.pesos) * unnest(vd.pesos)
from vetor_query vq
cross join vetor_documento vd;
```

However, it yields this error:

> Functions and operators can take at most one set argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the handy feature of the `unnest()` function to unnest multiple arrays in parallel.

Do that in a `LATERAL` join, multiply per resulting row and feed that to an ARRAY constructor:

```
SELECT q.query_id, d.doc, qd.prod
FROM   vetor_query          q
CROSS  JOIN vetor_documento d
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT x*y FROM unnest(q.pesos, d.pesos) t(x, y)) AS prod
   ) qd;
```

This is assuming all arrays have the same length, else surplus elements are filled with NULL.

Related:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

The order in the resulting array corresponds to the original order of elements. But consider:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)