# PostgreSQL: IF EXISTS COMMENT ON TABLE

Tags: postgresql, exists

I am little bit stucked with task IF EXIST.

I have several lines query with the COMMENTS ON TABLE function

```
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table1';
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table2 IS 'Comment for table2';
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table3 IS 'Comment for table3';
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table3 IS 'Comment for table4';
```

I want to do, when I will execute this query, if one of the table doesn't exist query will pass that and continue.

I tried to do that task with IF EXIST action, but it doesn't works like UPDATE or other actions. Where am I wrong?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class where relname='my_table1')
then
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table1';
IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class where relname='my_table2')
then
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table2';
IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class where relname='my_table3')
then
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table3';
IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class where relname='my_table4')
then
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table4';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class where relname='my_table1') THEN
    COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table1';
  END IF;

  IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class where relname='my_table2') THEN
    COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table2';
  END IF;
END
$do$
```

And check:

```
SELECT relname, obj_description(oid) 
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relname LIKE 'my_table%';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=797a577fe4f215f438127f3a15281724)**

Comment: Magnificent! That's what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (Postgres 10) no `IF EXISTS` for the [`COMMENT` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html). You'll have to check for existence one or the other way to avoid exceptions - which which lead to `ROLLBACK` for your complete transaction.

So one option would be to run separate transactions an just ignore any errors:

```
BEGIN;
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table1 IS 'Comment for table1';
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table2 IS 'Comment for table2';
COMMIT;

-- etc.
```

***Or*** you test with `IF` like [@lad2025 provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137732/939860).

***Or***, you might shorten the code with `to_regclass()`, which returns NULL for non-existent tables. See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _tbls text[] :=
      '{my_table1
      , my_table2
      , my_table3
      , my_table4}';
   _comments text[] :=
      '{"Comment for table1"
      , "Comment for table2"
      , NULL
      , "Comment for table4"}';
BEGIN
EXECUTE 
(SELECT string_agg('COMMENT ON TABLE ' || to_regclass(t) || ' IS ' || quote_nullable(c), '; ')
 FROM   unnest(_tbls, _comments) t(t, c));
END
$do$;
```

You can also delete any comment this way (reset it to NULL). Also note the use of [`quote_nullable()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

Check:

```
SELECT t1 AS table, obj_description(t1) AS table_comment
FROM  (SELECT to_regclass(t) AS t1
       FROM unnest('{my_table1, my_table2, my_table3, my_table4}'::text[]) t) sub;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=90094cf681e857b8082f98876b3f27e0)*

Related:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

Comment: Hello. Also thank you for your advice for that actions with COMMENTs, also but I am still use PostgreSQL 9.4. But I will be keep in mind your info about PostgreSQL 10, thanks.

Comment: @mulrus: Oh, everything of the above works with pg 9.4 (which should be declared in the questions to begin with!). Just stating that there is still no `IF EXISTS` for `COMMENT` in pg 10.

Comment: also mentioned on PostgreSQL 8.4 that DO function doesn't work, but I added $$ with the create or declare function action and everything fine.