# Retrieve rows from tables by primary key in order of given ID lists?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

For a given list of primary keys (with a single id column as primary key), I want to retrieve the rows pertaining to those ids in order from the database. If the id doesn't exist in the database, then that specific row should be all nulls.

I have two such lists of equal length, for two different tables in the database. I want to do a side-by-side join of the two tables (on the server side if possible).

We have two id lists: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[3, 2, 4, 1]`.
Query using first list on first table retrieves:

```
 id    c1
----  ----
 1     a
 2     b
 3     c
 4     d
```

Query using second list on second table retrieves:

```
 id    c2
----  ----
 3     g
 2     h
 4     i
 1     j
```

Final result should be:

```
 c1    c2
----  ----
 a     g
 b     h
 c     i
 d     j
```

Comment: It's okay if the primary key lookup fails for a given id instead of returning all nulls as long as it would throw an exception.

Comment: Please include the actual queries _and_ the sample data for each table.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the lists as *arrays* and unnest in parallel:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM   unnest ('{1, 2, 3, 4}'::int[]
             , '{3, 2, 4, 1}'::int[]) AS i(id1, id2)
LEFT   JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t1.id = i.id1
LEFT   JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t2.id = i.id2;
```

Using 2x `LEFT JOIN` guarantees that every index is represented in the output, even if no row is found in one or both tables - then you get NULL values instead.

Assuming the `id` columns of `tbl1` & `tbl2` to be `UNIQUE`, or this can create a "cross join by proxy". See:

- [INSERT from a SELECT combined with a single value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65877/3684)

If you also want preserve the sort order, add `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM   unnest ('{1, 2, 3, 4}'::int[]
             , '{3, 2, 4, 1}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY i(id1, id2, ord)
LEFT   JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t1.id = i.id1
LEFT   JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t2.id = i.id2
ORDER  BY ord;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT AA.C1,BB.C2 FROM (
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.id) As row_num, * FROM @tbl1 A ) AS AA
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) As row_num, * FROM @tbl2 A) AS BB
ON AA.row_num =BB.row_num)
```