# Select rows where elements of two arrays don't match a pattern

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I try to write a query where I select rows based one a `LIKE` pattern that has to match none of the entries of an array. What I have is the current one

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * from unnest(a) WHERE  unnest LIKE '%XYZ%' )))
```

Actually what I want is pairs - so it is more like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
NOT (
  (EXISTS (select * from unnest(a) as A, unnest(b) as B  WHERE  A||B LIKE '%xyz%abc%' )) OR
  (EXISTS (select * from unnest(a) as A, unnest(b) as B  WHERE  A||B LIKE '%abc%xyz%' ))
)
```

This works for me but looks rather unwieldy. Is there prettier/more efficient solution to this? What I am find the most irksome is the `SELECT` as part of the `WHERE` clause to unroll arrays.

some points:

- In my case `xyz` and `abc` will not appear together as substrings in a single array entry (e.g. nothing like `xyzblaabc`exists)
- Both arrays have exactly the same number of elements (they are actually derived from another query)
- no null elements (but even if that would still work as then I don't have a pair of `abc` and `xyz`)

**Edit:**

Clarification: a row contains A as `{rxyz,foo, bar}` and B as `{other, abc, this}` should not be returned as it contains the `rxyz` in one array and `abc` in the other

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM(
 SELECT *
    FROM   (select 1 as ID, '{rxyz,foo,bar}'::varchar[] as a, '{abc,other,this}'::varchar[] as b) row1  UNION
 SELECT *
    FROM   (select 2 as ID, '{rxyz,foo,bar}'::varchar[] as a, '{other,rabc,this}'::varchar[] as b) row1  UNION
 SELECT *
    FROM   (select 3 as ID, '{else,foo,bar}'::varchar[] as a, '{abc,other,this}'::varchar[] as b) row2

    ) mytable
WHERE   
NOT (
  (EXISTS (select * from unnest(a) as A, unnest(b) as B  WHERE  A||'-|-'||B LIKE '%xyz%-|-%abc%' OR B||'-|-'||A LIKE '%xyz%-|-%abc%' )))
```

returns only row3. In my use case I can guaranty that `-|-` is not part of either list making it possible to separate these.

Comment: *"This works ... " - or does it? See answer.

Comment: So in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ea8f59ed2b97e07ee7933660ace36173), only 1-3 would qualify?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter in that one, everything but 4 should be returned.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't add up. Your query applied to the fiddle returns a different set: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bbf30602190d27ceb9ddd16cd66ee0b8)* Please provide an ***exact*** definition of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter As mentioned `abc` and `xyz`, in my case, are not going to be part of the same string. In your example they are in 7 and 8 - I missed that sorry. So 4, 7 and 8 are filtered out "correctly". The arrays are actually result of an `array_agg()` on other data. So I know that they will always have the same size.

Comment: Then your last query looks good, mostly. But *A)* the regexp pattern is broken (typo, I guess). And *B)* Still breaks with different number of elements (cannot apply, you say, but be sure to document the trap) or NULL elements like I explained in my answer. Please clean up your question with the exact properties of the setup and the exact definition of what you want. And trim the noise. :) I am out of time now.

Comment: Actually you are right the last query is not what I want. So need to make it more complex

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest both into a single derived table:

```
select *
from mytable
where not exists (select *
                  from unnest(a,b) as x(a,b)
                  where x.a like '%xyz%'
                     or x.b like '%xyz%'
                     or x.a like '%abc%'
                     or x.b like '%abc%')
```

Comment: Thanks - I was not aware of `unest(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1):

The updated task description is:

*Eliminate rows where any element of text array `a` contains one of ('abc', 'xyz') and any element of text array `b` contains the other.*

Your second query achieves that, but at terrible cost. `unnest(a) as A, unnest(b)` combines every element of array `a` with every element of array `b` - a Cartesian product, O(N²), makes performance deteriorate quickly with longer arrays.

Try one of these instead:

Test against concatenated strings with `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl t, array_to_string(a, '|') AS a_string, array_to_string(b, '|') AS b_string
WHERE (a_string LIKE '%abc%' AND b_string LIKE '%xyz%'
   OR  a_string LIKE '%xyz%' AND b_string LIKE '%abc%') IS NOT TRUE;
```

Make sure to choose a separator that cannot produce false matches. `'|'` in the example.

Test against concatenated strings with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM array_to_string(a, '|') a_string
             , array_to_string(b, '|') b_string
   WHERE  a_string LIKE '%abc%' AND b_string LIKE '%xyz%'
      OR  a_string LIKE '%xyz%' AND b_string LIKE '%abc%'
   );
```

Test unnested elements with `LATERAL` subquery;

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT bool_or(a_elem LIKE '%abc%') AND bool_or(b_elem LIKE '%xyz%') 
       OR bool_or(a_elem LIKE '%xyz%') AND bool_or(b_elem LIKE '%abc%') AS exclude
   FROM   unnest(t.a,t.b) e(a_elem, b_elem)
   ) x ON exclude IS NOT TRUE;
```

Test unnested elements with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM unnest(t.a,t.b) AS e(a_elem, b_elem)
   HAVING bool_or(a_elem LIKE '%abc%') AND bool_or(b_elem LIKE '%xyz%') 
       OR bool_or(a_elem LIKE '%xyz%') AND bool_or(b_elem LIKE '%abc%')
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=21af3d03a56831a6d55722e6e887cbf6)*

The last one is my favorite. NNot sure which one performs best. All of them should perform substantially faster than what you have now.

About `unnest(a,b)`:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

#### Some comments on your points

> In my case `xyz` and `abc` will not appear together as substrings in a single array entry (e.g. nothing like `xyzblaabc`exists).

That's a big assumption. There may be good reasons for it, but are you sure there are no corner cases, not now, not ever? Else your code will break silently later and it will be extremely hard to determine the cause.

> Both arrays have exactly the same number of elements (they are actually derived from another query)

The most efficient query would then typically be to apply the filter at the source, in that other query - if at all possible. Might even use an appropriate index. Like, a trigram index:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

> no null elements (but even if that would still work as then I don't have a pair of `abc` and `xyz`)

Fair enough. But be wary of NULL values doing what you want if there *are* some.

Comment: I added a bit of clarification to what I want - sorry

Comment: @Lutz: I wrote a new answer to address that.

Comment: Actually what I was hoping for was something to replace the whole `NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM unnest WHERE )` with something more compact and readable (like the inverse of  `x like any (array of conditions)`). Guess I have to stick with that. As for applying at the source - does not work here.

Comment: So somthing along the lines of `not ((any a like '%xyz%' and any b like '%abc%') or (any b like '%xyz%' and any a like '%abc%')) `But that all I could come up with was the `not exists  in sub-querry`

Comment: @Lutz: Please respond to my request in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262472/select-rows-where-elements-of-two-arrays-dont-match-a-pattern#comment106598321_60262472. And is the assumption at the top of my answer correct? It's hard to discuss details while the question isn't completely clear.

Comment: I had an error in one of the queries that it only excluded if they where in the same place. Positions with in teach array are not important. It's about the pure existence of the elements in separate arrays. So exclude anything that has in a abc as a substring in one array and xyz in the other. having abc and xyz in one array  but neither of the two in the second should not be filtered out.

Comment: @Lutz: Douglas Adams tells a story about looking for an answer before getting the question right. Got them *42* and they had to start over ...