# How to unnest multiple postgres jsonb arrays in parallel

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, sql-function

I want to iterate over the elements of two jsonb arrays at once. If it was only one array I know I could simply use json_array_elements and everything would be fine. But for multiple arrays I'm having a hard time to come up with a solution.

Similar to [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel), but just for jsonb arrays. So I know that for regular postgres arrays there is unnest(anyarray, anyarray [, ...]).

Here's a snippet of my schematic data scenario:

```
SELECT *
FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id": 0, "array_a": ["a", "c"], "array_b": ["b" , "d"]}]') 
AS example(id jsonb, array_a jsonb, array_b jsonb)
```

That I want to transform to:

```
a | b

c | d
```

Hope someone can help me with that.

Best wishes
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with ordinality` and a join to zip the values together:

```
with invars as (
  SELECT *
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id": 0, "array_a": ["a", "c"], "array_b": ["b" , "d"]}]') 
      AS example(id jsonb, array_a jsonb, array_b jsonb)
)
select a1, b1
  from invars
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(array_a) with ordinality as ela(a1, rn)
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(array_b) with ordinality as elb(b1, rn)
 where ela.rn = elb.rn;
```

[Working fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e3deee4828f524b6380aa0642a917db4)

If the arrays can be of differing lengths, then this works even though there is likely a more elegant solution:

```
with invars as (
  SELECT *
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id": 0, "array_a": ["a", "c", "e"], "array_b": ["b" , "d", "f", "h"]}]')
      AS example(id jsonb, array_a jsonb, array_b jsonb)
), a_side as (
  select a1, rn
    from invars
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(array_a) with ordinality as ela(a1, rn)
), b_side as (
  select b1, rn
    from invars
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(array_b) with ordinality as elb(b1, rn)
)
select a1, b1
  from a_side
       full join b_side
         on a_side.rn = b_side.rn
;
```

[Updated Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80b7e6b4d6558a7a8167d1ba90a3732d)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.
I just tried it out and stumbled upon the detail, that this "only works" for arrays of the same length. Do you have a solution that would also work for arrays with different lengths, leaving the entry of the other array zero?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` and `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT()` functions consecutively including `ORDINALITY` option

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT (elm -> 'array_a')::JSONB AS a, (elm -> 'array_b')::JSONB AS b
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(jsdata) 
  WITH ORDINALITY AS q(elm, i) 
)
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM t2
  JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(a) WITH ORDINALITY AS q1(col1, i) ON TRUE 
  JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(b) WITH ORDINALITY AS q2(col2, j) ON i=j
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1f265de68d73d8c585f9648372bc9744)</kbd>