# Unnest multiple array columns stored as text in lockstep

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number, unnest, set-returning-functions

I have the following table in Postgres 9.6:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_tbl(
  target_id integer NOT NULL
, machine_id integer NOT NULL
, dateread timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
, state text
, ftime text
, CONSTRAINT pk_sometable PRIMARY KEY (target_id, machine_id, dateread)
 );
```

With data like:

| targetID | MachineID | DateRead | State | FTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '0|1|0' | '850|930|32000' |
| 60000 | 31 | '2021-09-29 16:35:13' | '0|0|0' | '980|1050|30000' |

The important part is `state` and `ftime`. I need to unnest elements and keep their order. This generates steps.

For example, the first row will be:

| targetID | MachineID | DateRead | State | FTime | Step |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '0' | '850' | 0 |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '1' | '930' | 1 |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '0' | '32000' | 2 |

The ORDER is important, because FTIME 850 ms is always FIRST and gets value 0 in STEP, then later 930 ms is the second and get step 1 and at last 32000 ms is the third and get step 2.

Currently, I resolve this by first using `string_to_array()` to transform the text to array, then `unnnest()`and finally use `row_number()` to assign the step number.

This work fantastically - except sometimes some index appears out of order. Like this for the first row:

| targetID | MachineID | DateRead | State | Ftime | Step |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '1' | '930' | 0 |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '0' | '32000' | 1 |
| 60000 | 30 | '2021-09-29 15:20:00' | '0' | '850' | 2 |

I do it over a thousands of records and practically all are ok, but later I must do statistics and need get min, max, average and get wrong values, so I check and i see are the index wrong (I move statistics with a massive ETL process) but if I execute the select checking the specific row with error it show perfect. So I assume than row_number have problems with index some times and this is very random.

This is the SQL that i use:

```
SELECT foo.target_id,
            dateread,
            foo.machine_id,
            foo.state,
            foo.ftime::integer,
            (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY foo.dateread, foo.machine_id, foo.target_id)) - 1 AS step
           FROM ( SELECT target_id,
                machine_id,
                dateread
                unnest(string_to_array(state, '|'::text))::integer AS state,
                unnest(string_to_array(ftime, '|'::text))::integer AS tiempo
               FROM some_table
               WHERE target_id IN (6000) AND dateread = '2021-06-09')foo
```

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Your precise table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints) and your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: Hi, this is the BASE TABLE:

'CREATE TABLE schema.sometable
(
  target_id integer NOT NULL,
  machine_id integer NOT NULL,
  dateread timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  state text,
  ftime text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_sometable PRIMARY KEY (target_id, machine_id, dateread)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE schema.sometable
  OWNER TO postgres;'

AND I am using Postgres 9.6.

Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: [Edit] the table definition into the question, not into a comment, please.

Comment: Ok, i did it. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant way is to use the special implementation of `unnest()` for multiple input arrays in a `LATERAL` subquery and attach `WITH ORDINALITY`:

```sql
SELECT t.target_id, t.dateread, t.machine_id, u.state, u.tiempo
     , ord - 1 AS step
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(state, '|')::int[]
                         , string_to_array(ftime, '|')::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(state, tiempo, ord) ON true
WHERE  target_id = 60000
AND    dateread = '2021-09-29 15:20:00'   -- adapted
ORDER  BY t.target_id, t.dateread, t.machine_id, step;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9da91551b4529a52fa474eb125da049e)*

Since `state` and `ftime` can be `NULL`, I use `LEFT JOIN ... ON true` to keep such rows in the result.

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Of course, **what you really should do** is this:

1. Unfriend the guy who designed the database. (PC version of my real advice.)
2. Install a current Postgres version. See:  https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/
3. Create a new database with a proper relational design.
4. Migrate your data. (And keep a backup of your original to be safe.)
5. Burn the old DB and never speak of it again.

A proper (normalized) relational design in modern Postgres could look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  tbl_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, target_id integer NOT NULL
, machine_id integer NOT NULL
, read_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT tbl_uni UNIQUE (target_id, machine_id, read_timestamp)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_step (
  tbl_id int REFERENCES tbl ON DELETE CASCADE
, step int NOT NULL
, state int NOT NULL
, tiempo int NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT tbl_step_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tbl_id, step)
);
```

Then your query would just be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl 
LEFT   JOIN tbl_step USING (tbl_id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwin, i was checking your sql and works great, even compare massive load before and after and find over 30k differences. I've been checking the differences and so far and all are perfect.

Really thanks a lot master. Have a nice weekend.